# unobfuscating string function

Tags: c++, qt, modulus

Suppose I have a string of characters: "

```
String input = "5;5;5;5;"
```

And insert them into this function:

```
for(int i=input.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
    output += (QChar)((input[i].unicode() + 32) + 8160);
}

return output;
```

Output: `※‵※‵※‵※‵`

How would I write a decrypting function?

I know I can do this:

```
for(int i=input.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
     output += (QChar)(input.unicode()-32 - 8160);
}
return output;
```

But why does this work:

```
for(int i=input.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
     output += (QChar)((input.unicode()-32)%255); //Get ASCII character
}
return output;
```

Is it just a coincidence? Or am I just not understanding the math. I know that trying to reverse a modulus operation is next to impossible, unless you know the range of `x` you want.

```
(1 + x) % 4 = 2
```

x can be 5,9,13,...

Answer (score 1):

The second decryption function works because 8160 happens to be a multiple of 255, and the original value is contained in the 0-254 range.

Looking at your example `x` can be any number of the form `1+4n` for any `n`. Similarly, for the second decryption function, `input.unicode()-32+255*n % 255` has the same value for any small values of `n` (ie. so long as there are no overflows during computations), including the case `n=-32` which corresponds to `255*(-32)=-8160`.